# Accessing last value in a time series dataframe with pandas and plotly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

How would I grab the very last value of a time series?

I have a df with timeseries info for many countries, that tracks several variables and does some simple averaging etc.

I just want to grab the most recent value / values for each country and graph it with plotly. I have tried using .last() but not really sure where to fit it into the loop.

I need to grab both the last value for one chart, and the last n values for another chart.

```
# Daily Change

country = "X"

#Plot rolling average new cases


data =  [go.Scatter(x=df_join.loc[f'{country}']['Date'],
                y=df_join.loc[f'{country}']['Pct Change'],
                mode='lines',
                name='Pct Change')]


layout = go.Layout(title=f'{country}: Pct Change')

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
pyo.plot(fig)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you need to filter your dataframe before hand :

```
dates = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('today'),pd.Timestamp('today') + pd.DateOffset(days=5))

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : dates, 'ID' : ['A','A','A','B','B','B']})


df2 = df.loc[df.groupby(['ID'])['Date'].idxmax()]


print(df2)

                        Date ID
2 2020-05-16 12:26:06.772939  A
5 2020-05-19 12:26:06.772939  B
```

Comment: @CormacDaly don't forget to accept this answer if it helped